# Best Practice for Executing Ensemble Methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I am running the sample code below.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\my_path\\test.csv', header=0, encoding = 'unicode_escape')
df = df.fillna(0)

X = df1.drop(columns = ['PRICE','MATURITYDATE'])
y = df1['PRICE']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#split data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
#create new a knn model
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
#create a dictionary of all values we want to test for n_neighbors
params_knn = {'n_neighbors': np.arange(1, 25)}
#use gridsearch to test all values for n_neighbors
knn_gs = GridSearchCV(knn, params_knn, cv=5)
#fit model to training data
knn_gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

#save best model
knn_best = knn_gs.best_estimator_
#check best n_neigbors value
print(knn_gs.best_params_)



# RANDOM FOREST
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
#create a new random forest classifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
#create a dictionary of all values we want to test for n_estimators
params_rf = {'n_estimators': [50, 100, 200]}
#use gridsearch to test all values for n_estimators
rf_gs = GridSearchCV(rf, params_rf, cv=5)
#fit model to training data
rf_gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

#save best model
rf_best = rf_gs.best_estimator_
#check best n_estimators value
print(rf_gs.best_params_)


# REGRESSION
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
#create a new logistic regression model
log_reg = LogisticRegression()
#fit the model to the training data
log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

#test the three models with the test data and print their accuracy scores
print('knn: {}'.format(knn_best.score(X_test, y_test)))
print('rf: {}'.format(rf_best.score(X_test, y_test)))
print('log_reg: {}'.format(log_reg.score(X_test, y_test)))


# VOTING CLASSIFIER
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
#create a dictionary of our models
estimators=[('knn', knn_best), ('rf', rf_best), ('log_reg', log_reg)]
#create our voting classifier, inputting our models
ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators, voting='hard')
```

It's all from the link below

https://towardsdatascience.com/ensemble-learning-using-scikit-learn-85c4531ff86a

The problem that I'm running into with each of these methods is always this:

`ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'`

I guess everything needs to be converted into a categorical type or, perhaps, one hot encoding needs to be applied.  Is this correct?  What is the best way to deal with this kind of issue?  I'm hoping to keep things simple and very generic, without introducing custom coding.  This is why I am leaning towards the scikit-learn libraries.  I'd greatly appreciate any/all thoughts and insights.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Is your label `y` a continuous variable (Price?)? If so, you need a regressor, not a classifier.

Comment: Yes, it is continuous.  So how do I get this to work?

Comment: You need a regression algorithm, e.g. `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()` or `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor()`. Classification models, like in your post, are only for categorical outputs.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks!!